# How to set selectManyCheckbox value?

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

My problem is I can't set the default values when I visit the page first time.
My code is run very well.But my requirement is when I am visit the page first  time the first checkBox is default selected.
 
I have the following jsf code

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{newUser.newUserModel.selectedCheckBox}" layout="lineDirection"
                      onclick="document.getElementById('addNewUserForm:checkBox').click();">
    <f:selectItems value="#{newUser.newUserModel.userRoleComboBox}" />
    <f:ajax />
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

My Controller name is newUser and in my controller I got the values of selected checkBox.And the code is follows:

```
for(String selectedCheckBox: newUserModel.getSelectedCheckBox()){
    System.out.println(value of selectckeckBox"+selectedCheckBox);
}
```

My Bean name is newUserModel ad the declaration is as followas:

```
private List<SelectItem> userRoleComboBox;
private List<String> selectedCheckBox = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and the getter & setter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply have to initialize your `selectCheckBox` properly by adding value of each `SelectItem` you want to select.

**Example :**

```
// Assuming your userRoleComboBox is already initialized
this.selectedCheckBox.add((String)this.userRoleComboBox.get(0).getValue());
```

This will pre-select the first choice.

Comment: this.newUserModel.getSelectedCheckBox().add((String)this.newUserModel.getUserRoleComboBox().get(0).getValue());

Comment: thanks for your help it work..you just add the string value in the list